# How to authenticate in Datastax Studio?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-studio

I have Datastax Community 3.0.4 installed on Windws 8.1 and I am trying to use Datastax Studio 1.0.2. The question is that I use authentication in Cassandra and therefore I need to authenticate also in Datastax Studio.

How can I solve it? How can I authenticate in Datastax Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Studio and Community Edition are not meant to work together.

DataStax Studio is meant for use with DataStax **Enterprise** (in particular, for use exploring graph data in DSE). The Community edition you have installed only contains a distribution of Apache Cassandra (+ OpsCenter) and *not* DataStax Enterprise. So if you want to use DataStax Studio, you're going to have to get a copy of DataStax Enterprise first.

Since you're on Windows (and not on Windows 10), your options are a little limited. DSE doesn't run on Windows natively, so you'll have to use a Virtual Machine of some kind. There is a [Sandbox image available](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/welcome) from the DataStax Academy downloads page for both VirtualBox or VMWare, or you can always create your own VM (running Ubuntu or the Linux flavor of your choice) and [Install DSE](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/install/installTOC.html) yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: Everything my colleague Luke said here is totally accurate, but in the interest of future-proofing this answer I will point out that Studio 2.0.0 (planned for Spring 2017, approximately) will also have support for CQL.